# Opening an UTF-8 CSV containing HTML with Excel

Tags: html, excel, csv, utf-8

I have a multi-language website and i need to open an csv in Excel for the translation company to translate the content from english to mandarin.

The file is UTF-8 and when I open it by double clicking, Excel doesn't care what charset it is and some characters are messed up. When I open it through Data->Import Text, select UTF-8 and pick my semicolon delimiter and such, the characters are good but Excel generates new rows if it comes across a html closing tag

Any help? I'd be glad to upload the CSV somewhere so you can try for yourselves.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen with the HTML? I'm not sure if Excel even supports having multiple block elements in one cell.

Comment: Well, all of the HTML code should remain in the same cell. The code should just be visible there so when the translating company translates the text within the tags and returns it to me. I can just import it with the html tags in it. The client made the content of the website with a wysiwyg. That's why there's HTML in my cells. I still need the html so I can't just remove it from the CSV. Thanks for your comment btw!

Comment: Try replacing the `<` characters with `&lt;` in a text editor.

Comment: Well, that solves the new rows indeed. But I'll have to replace the characters again when imported in excel. This will mean an increase in workload, because i'm not just dealing with one table of terms. But it sure is a temporary solution. Thanks!

Comment: For a long term solution try to get away from Excel. It's obviously the wrong tool for the job. There are translation tools and websites out there, that would be more suitable, however I'm not familiar with them, so I can't recommend any. Maybe open a new question (possibly on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)) and describe the larger picture. I'm sure someone can give better advice.

Comment: I just wanted to post the solution here. Throw Excel in the garbage and use OpenOffice Calc. It did the job perfectly! When I open the CSV with Calc, it automatically asks for the charset and it had no problems with keeping the HTML in one cell instead of adding new rows for each tag.

Answer (score 3):

Throw Excel in the garbage and use OpenOffice Calc. It did the job perfectly! When I open the CSV with Calc, it automatically asks for the charset and it had no problems with keeping the HTML in one cell instead of adding new rows for each tag